# how to navigate from an activity to a compose function

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am looking for a way to Navigate from an activity to a compose function, but I can't find any way to make this happen as I can't use the Navgraph inside the activity as I use it in the main activity, I had to use an activity to apply Google maps the way I want as not everything on maps is supported in compose yet.
so is there is anyway to handle this?

Comment: direct navigation from activity to compose is not supported. the supported way is,  you can navigate to another activity or a fragment that contains a compose view. On the other hand, you can use AndroidView inside a compose view and apply any logic to the native google maps component in the factory method. Even I implemented a webview (which is not supported by jetpack compose now) inside a modal sheet by using the same logics.

Comment: I actually thought about that as its the same way I implemented the WebView, it would be the solution for sure, but I wanted to seek the easier way if navigating from an activity to compose is supported. thx